# Como eliminar el marco de una foto tomada con android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

El problema que tengo es que cuando toma una foto desde mi aplicación y procedo a guardarla esta se almacena con un marco a los costados.

Quería saber cómo puedo eliminar este marco.

Dejo mi código

```
private void openCameraIntent() {
    Intent pictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (pictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {

        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        Uri photoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, getPackageName() + ".provider", photoFile);
        pictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoUri);
        ivimagen.setImageURI(Uri.parse(imageFilePath));
        ivimagen.buildDrawingCache();
        startActivityForResult(pictureIntent, 1);
    }
}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    imageFilePath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te puedo asegurar que lo que comentas no esta relacionado al código, en realidad tu cámara esta configurada para tomar la imagen con ese aspecto

Comúnmente la cámara esta configurada con un aspecto de **16:9**, en tu caso posiblemente esta configurada como **4:3** ya que la imagen tiene un aspecto casi cuadrado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El aspecto **16:9** tiene un aspecto rectangular, si la imagen se muestra en tu dispositivo con orientación horizontal, la imagen se mostrará con espacios a los extremos :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Pero en realidad la imagen se guarda correctamente, el espacio negro es el fondo.**